# Cucumber steps implementation in kotlin isn't recognized in feature file

Tags: android, kotlin, cucumber

I have this feature file :

```
  Given I launch google using chrome as browser
   When I search by kotlin
   Then I will see 32 results per page
```

where my properties file has the content :

```
e1=www.google.com
field= kotlin
nr=32
```

However, the third steps from my feature file appears as if they aren't implemented : https://www.screencast.com/t/fP9vjdToSI

I have implemented the steps in a kotlin class :

```
init {
        Given("^I launch \"(.*)\" using chrome as browser$") { element: String ->
            // load the properties file
//            prop.load(file)
            prop.load(StepsDefinition::class.java!!.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("application-test.properties"))
            // set the properties
            prop.getProperty("el1")
            val element= prop.getProperty("el1")
            println(prop.getProperty("el1"))
            driver.get(element)

            When("^I search by \"(.*)\"$") { field: String ->
                val button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=\"" + field+ "\"]" +
                        "| //button[contains(text(),\"" + field+ "\")]"))
                button.isDisplayed
                button.click()
            }

            Then("^I see \"(.*)\" results per page") { nr: String ->
                val wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
               Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains(nr))
            }
```

Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have cucumber currently set up on my machine so I can't really verify what I'm saying, however I'd say it's just a mismatch between the step definition and the step in the feature.

Your step definition expects the keyword to be wrapped in quotes, while in your feature file you're not using any quotes. The same should apply to the `When` step (same error) and to the `Then` step, where you put an extra `will`.